# HtppServletRequest getParameterValues Returning Null

Tags: java, forms, nullpointerexception, thymeleaf

I have the following form in thymeleaf (with the problem sections being the selectpicker class):

```
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="superPersonName" class="col-3 col-form-label">
                                Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <input type="text" name="superPersonName" 
                                       id="superPersonName" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="superPersonDesc" class="col-3 col-form-label">
                                Description:</label>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <input type="text" name="superPersonDesc" 
                                       id="superPersonDesc" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="powerNames" class="col-3 col-form-label">
                                Powers:</label>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <select class="form-control selectpicker" th:field="*{powers}" id="powerNames" name="powerNames" multiple>
                                    <option th:each="power : ${powers}"
                                            th:value="${power.name}"
                                            th:text="${power.name}">power
                                    </option>
                                </select> 
                            </div>
                        </div>    
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="organizationNames" class="col-3 col-form-label">
                                Organization:</label>
                            <div class="col-9">
                                <select class="form-control selectpicker" th:field="*{organizations}" id="organizationNames" name="organizationNames" multiple>

                                    <option th:each="org : ${organizations}"
                                            th:value="${org.name}"
                                            th:text="${org.name}">power
                                    </option>
                                </select> 
                            </div>   
                        </div>      
                        
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Villain</button>
                    </form>
```

and the following controller methods

```
    @GetMapping("villains")
    public String displayVillains(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("errors", violations);
        List<SuperPerson> villains = service.getVillains();
        model.addAttribute("villains", villains);
        model.addAttribute("powers", service.getPowers());
        model.addAttribute("organizations", service.getOrganizations());
        return "villains";
    }

    @PostMapping("addVillain")
    public String addVillain(HttpServletRequest request){
        violations.clear();
        SuperPerson villain = service.createSuperPerson(request, true);
        Validator validate = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        violations = validate.validate(villain);

        if(violations.isEmpty()) {
            service.addSuperPerson(villain);
        }
        return "redirect:/villains";
    }
```

and the following method that handles the creation of the object

```
    public SuperPerson createSuperPerson(HttpServletRequest request, boolean isVillain) {
        SuperPerson superPerson = new SuperPerson();
        String name = request.getParameter("superPersonName");
        String description = request.getParameter("superPersonDesc");
        
        String[] organizationNames = request.getParameterValues("organizationNames");
        String[] powerNames = request.getParameterValues("powerNames");
        
        List<Organization> organizations = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Power> powers = new ArrayList<>();
        
       
            for(String orgName : organizationNames){
                organizations.add(orgDao.getOrganizationByName(orgName));
            }       
       
        
        
            for(String powerName : powerNames){
                powers.add(powerDao.getPowerByName(powerName));
            }
        
        
          
        superPerson.setName(name);
        superPerson.setDescription(description);
        superPerson.setVillain(isVillain);
        superPerson.setOrganizations(organizations);
        superPerson.setPowers(powers);
        return superPerson;
    }
```

The error I'm getting when attempting to add a villain is a nullpointerexception referencing the organizationNames array for loop at line 250.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No message available
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jdm.superherosightings.service.ServiceLayer.createSuperPerson(ServiceLayer.java:250)
    at com.jdm.superherosightings.controllers.VillainController.addVillain(VillainController.java:56)
```

I've checked and both powerNames and organizationNames are null arrays within this method. The form is on the "villains" page and the model has both powers and organizations list attributes and the form itself is how I want it to be.
I cannot seem to figure out why the getParameterValues call is returning nothing when I am selecting the options I have on my form (there isn't any input validation at the moment, I'm just making sure my input is good for testing). Can anyone see why the arrays are null?

Comment: Spring has an extensive infrastructure for doing automatic mapping for you (using either `@ModelAttribute` or `@RequestBody` depending on the organization of your HTTP API). You should almost never handle `HttpServletRequest` directly; your entire `createSuperPerson` is unnecessary (and you can replace all your validation stuff with an `@Valid` annotation on the controller parameter).